# how can I divide strings from array with a comma in js/css?

Tags: javascript, css, ejs

I'm using `ejs` template engine to populate data on my page.

My json file contains the following fields:

```
var PhotosSchema = new Schema({
  photo_url: {type: String},
  thumb_url: {type: String},
  hashtags: {type: [String]}
});
```

I have the following html code so far:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src=<%= photo.thumb_url %> >
  <div class="caption">
    <p><% for(var i=0; i<photo.hashtags.length; i++) {%>
    <a href="http://example.com/<%=photo.hashtags[i]%>"><%=photo.hashtags[i] %></a>
    <% } %>
    | <a href="<%= photo.photo_url  %>">full resolution</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and it shows hashtags below the photo, but they are not divided with a comma. For example it looks like this:

```
one two three
```

how can I modify my code so that it divides hashtags with `,` sign, but does not add this character to the end, for example:

```
one, two, three
```

This one would not be correct:

```
one, two, three,
```

Comment: add an if and see if it is alst if it is than do not output it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case, add a ternary operator. `i != photo.hashtags.length - 1 ? "," : ""`

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src=<%= photo.thumb_url %> >
    <div class="caption">

        <p><% for(var i=0; i<photo.hashtags.length; i++) {%>
        <a href="http://example.com/<%=photo.hashtags[i]%>">
            <%=photo.hashtags[i] %> <%= i != photo.hashtags.length - 1 ? "," : "" %>
        </a>
        <% } %>
        | <a href="<%= photo.photo_url  %>">full resolution</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop for all but the last element, and add ", " after each hashtag. And do the last hashtag separately after the loop

```
<div class="thumbnail">
        <img src=<%= photo.thumb_url %> >
        <div class="caption">
            <p><% for(var i=0; i<photo.hashtags.length - 1; i++) {%>
            <a href="http://example.com/<%=photo.hashtags[i]%>"><%=photo.hashtags[i] %>, </a>
            <% } %>
            <a href="http://example.com/<%=photo.hashtags[i+1]%>"><%=photo.hashtags[i] %>
            | <a href="<%= photo.photo_url  %>">full resolution</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```